# How to retrieve a database record associated with a work item?

Tags: genexus

We would like to retrieve or display the corresponding database record associated with a instance of a process in GXFlow.
The requirement is for the user to know which request has been processed, when task has been completed.
Genexus 18 U8
.NET Web

Example: If you double-click a process in the "My Processes" area, a web panel will be presented with the corresponding database record associated with that instance.

[image]

[genexus](/questions/tagged/genexus)Genexus 18 U8 .NET Web